# How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

Basically, I can use this method only for image. The question is how can I use this method for text types.

Image Method:

```
<a href="#"><img id="random"></a>
<script>
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "image1.jpg";
image[1] = "image2.jpg";
image[2] = "image3.jpg";
image[3] = "image4.jpg";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
```

Text HTML look like this:

```
<span id="xx" href="#" class="text-ellipsis">Text Here</span>
```

I tried like this:

```html
<a id="randomx" href="#">Text Here</a>
<script>
  var image = new Array();
  text[0] = "TEXT1";
  text[1] = "TEXT2";
  text[2] = "TEXT3";
  text[3] = "TEXT4";
  var size = text.length
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

  $('#randomx').attr('src', text[x]);
</script>
```

Comment: [Have you looked at the jQuery api reference](http://api.jquery.com/)?

Comment: Same concept: build an array of possible data, choose data randomly, and set the content to the randomly selected value. Where are you getting stuck? I suggest showing what you tried and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: I tried to change image sides like text however, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qr1pqawj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. you are not initializing your text array, but attempting to fill it with data
2. you are not filling the text of the a tag, but trying to change it's source.

this will work just fine:

```
<a id="randomx" href="#">Text Here</a>
<script>
  var text = new Array();
  text[0] = "TEXT1";
  text[1] = "TEXT2";
  text[2] = "TEXT3";
  text[3] = "TEXT4";
  var size = text.length
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

  $('#randomx').text(text[x]);
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL701umq/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a thought, try  not using jQuery for every little thing.

```js
 var el = document.getElementById("randomx");
var image = new Array();
image[0] = "TEXT1";
image[1] = "TEXT2";
image[2] = "TEXT3";
image[3] = "TEXT4";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

el.src = image[x];       //set source
el.innerHTML = image[x]; //set link text
```

```html
<a id="randomx" href="#"></a>
```